# Running total in Mysql Domo

Tags: mysql

need some help. Trying to solve this, kindly help.
Have a table of sales with some months with zero sales.  My running total is failing to return a cumulative value for months with zero sales.

```
Product Jan Feb Mar April   May Jun

Bread   4   2   0   2   3   4

runTot  4   6   0   8   11  15
```

Expected Solution

```
Product Jan Feb Mar April   May Jun

Bread   4   2   0   2   3   4

runTot  4   6   6   8   11  15
```

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055). Chapters #5 and #3.

Comment: Domo is a BI tool. If you produce the above result with  one of its built-in features, then you need to ask this question on their support forum.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.